# How to create an enum dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, enums

Is there a way that I can use to create Enums dynamically? I'm trying to get the names of tables inside a database and create a list of Enums which I would use when coding inside Visual Studio. Is it even possible?

I think I can get the name of tables in a database but the later part, I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an enum easily at runtime.

However, you can use a [T4 template](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) to query your database and create a code file that could be compiled in.

Comment: @Hossein - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: @Damiel A. White: Thank you thats a very good point to start with ;)

Answer (score 1):

There isnt a way of doing this, you could manually create an enum that represents the database,

Maybe it would be better if you used a `Dictionary<int, string>`

Comment: I dont want to use Dictionary<>,i want to make a class for using databases, and so i want to create a possibility that when the user , tries to lets say select from a table, the method which would need a table name , accepts an enum, and when user tries to choose one enum, sees all the available tables in his project.I'm trying to make it easier for the coder (possibly myself) by using enums in such a way.